# Continuous Map and Finite Sets

Tags: general-topology

The question is

> If $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is a continuous map and $Y$ has nonempty finite open sets, does $X$ have to have nonempty finite open sets?

I intend to give a counterexample, but I am not sure if the example is valid.

Consider $f : \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow  \{0\}$, where $f$ maps all the open sets in $\mathbb{Z}$ to the singleton set $\{0\}$. $Y$ has clearly nonempty finite open sets, and $X$ have infinite amount of open sets.

Is the counterexample valid?

Comment: Yes it's valid (I suppose you mean $f$ maps all $\mathbb Z$ to $0$).

Comment: Not sure why you pick $\mathbb Z$, as that's not usually considered as a topological space.  What topology did you have in mind?  The usual one, induced from the standard topology on $\mathbb R$, is the discrete topology which doesn't work for your example.   But, anyway, you could take *any* topological space ($\mathbb R$, for instance) and map it to your singleton space.

Comment: The question asks for non-empty finite open sets, not for finite number of non-empty open sets. The set $\mathbb Z$ indeed does have non-empty finite open sets.

Comment: @lulu thanks for the comment. I meant the subspace topology on $\mathbb{Z}$, with open sets derived from intersecting  with $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: But then your example is wrong.  That's the discrete topology on $\mathbb Z$, and *every* subset is open, including all the finite ones.  If you declared the indiscrete topology, then it works (and that would work if you used *any* infinite set).

Comment: @lulu but why? Isn't we supposed to show that $X$ ,($\mathbb{Z}$ in this case) contains infinite amount of elements, and the discrete topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ proves the point? I guess in other words, why does the discrete topology on $\mathbb{Z}$ have nonempty finite open sets?

Comment: I think you don't understand the question.  A "non-empty finite open set" would be an open subset of your topological space which consisted of finitely many points.  Since *every* subset of $\mathbb Z$ with the discrete topology is open, just take any finite subset.

Comment: @lulu You're right. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $Y$ be any space with a finite open set, and containing a point $y_0$. (For example, $\{y_0\}$ with its unique topology.)

Let $X$ be any space without finite open sets. (For example, $\mathbb R$ with the usual topology.)

Then $f:X\to Y$ defined by $f(x)=y_0$ is a constant map, and thus continuous, giving a counterexample to the question.